# how to print a php page with table data

Tags: php

I have a search results in a form which displays a particular persons details.
Here what I need is I should have a print page button and print that search result.
How is that posible in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the file -> print from the browser and use a [CSS print](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets)

If you want a button to print on the website, you will have to use Javascript

```
<form><input type="button" value=" Print this page "
onclick="window.print();return false;" /></form>
```

Comment: Thanks..and can i export it as pdf? is there any option for that?

Comment: @SK0004 if the person installed a PDF printer like this : http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/ yes they will be able to print it has a PDF.